# Migrating Exchange to new server hardware

Tags: exchange-2003

[Backstory](https://serverfault.com/questions/57500/windows-server-2000-hardware-question)

I'm following a recomendation by SpaceManSpiff (see ServerFault Backstory link above), I have a new Windows Server 2000 hardware up and running and I'm about install Exchange 2003 to begin the mailbox move.  However I'm not sure exactly how to go about joining the domain.  Should I just join the domain using System Properties, Network Identification, or should I setup the Active Directory for a second Domain Controller?

Keep in mind the ultimate goal is to move exchange from the old server to the new server then remove the old server (current DC) from the domain.  So at some point the new server needs to have AD but I'm not clear if that's before or after Exchange is installed.

Also, I know what you're thinking.  Don't worry, I'm planning an upgrade to Windows 2003 very soon, I can get Windows 2003 w/ 15 CAL for less then $100 from Techsoup.org.

Comment: wouldn't you really want to be going to Windows 2008, not 2003?

Comment: @warren: Exchange 2003 is not supported on 2008

Answer (score 2):

As best practice you should not have an exchange server running as a DC.

Add the server to the domain as a member server.
Install exhchange and add it to the existing exhchange organisation
move your mailboxes, and roles to the new server.
Update MX records, firewall for in bound smtp traffic (assuming yu=ou have only 1 exchange server)

for more info go to www.microsoft.com/exchange

Comment: I agree with this, don't make it a DC just yet. Win 2K with Exchange 2003 will make your machine take FOREVER when rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to be replacing your other DC/Exchange server with this one, you'd want to run "adprep" on the new server to join it to the domain.  Don't forget (since LOTS of people do) that when you remove the original machine from the domain, there's lots of stuff you have to do to the domain and old server first.  To start with, you need to transfer the FSMO roles to the new server.  Additionally, there are several Exchange roles that need to be migrated from the old server to the new...there's lots of white papers around about this to help you along your way...just search for "Exchange 2000 2003 Migration" on www.microsoft.com or in Google.

Also, just as a side note, you may want to consider going directly to Exchange 2007...which is what I did about 6-9 months ago.  MS is not going to be supporting Exchange 2003 for a whole lot longer (as far as patches go), and you have to buy the Exchange 2007 licenses anyway to be able to install Exchange 2003.  I assume that you're a NFP since you're ordering from Techsoup.org.  If you're having hardware requirement problems (assuming that's why you're not going to Exchange 2007), you may want to contact Dell, since they have great programs for NFPs.  I've done support for lots of local churches and libraries that use and love techsoup.org, and they've also had great luck with Dell giving them great pricing.

I hope this helps!  Good luck!

Comment: Well I'm working remotely using Dameware Remote Control and I joined the new server to the domain and now I can't connect to it anymore.  Seems to be the RPC service failed.

Comment: You don't want to run 'adprep' since he already has and exchange server the AD schema has already been extended. A simple 'dcpromo' will get the job done without messing with the schema.